# Extract Red Channel from Image

Tags: rgb, imagick

I have a Image say 'X' (RGB) from which i want to get Image of RED Channel using Imagick 
I tried refering http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/quantize

Comment: convert image.gif -channel R -separate red.gif // Red Channel Image

Comment: convert image.gif -channel G -separate green.gif // Green Channel Image

Comment: convert image.gif -channel B -separate blue.gif // Blue Channel Image

Comment: you can add your comments as an answer and accept it

Comment: The Imagick equivalent is separateImageChannel( ChannelValue ). See http://us3.php.net/manual/en/imagick.separateimagechannel.php

Answer (score 6):

The command you need can be found in the ImageMagick documentation at https://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/color_basics/#separate:

> ## Separating Channel Images
>
> The easiest way separating out the individual color channels is to use the "-separate" operator to extract the current contents of each channel as a gray-scale image.
>
> ```
> convert rose: -channel R -separate separate_red.gif
> convert rose: -channel G -separate separate_green.gif
> convert rose: -channel B -separate separate_blue.gif
> ```
>
> [image: Rose] [image: ==>] [image: Rose Red] [image: Rose Green] [image: Rose Blue]

(In these examples, the `rose:` parameter makes it use a small [built-in image](https://imagemagick.org/script/formats.php#builtin-images) of a rose for the input.)