# How to get RGB channel using Wand?

Tags: python, wand

I want to get a channel (Red, for example) from an Image using Wand in Python.

I already know how to get channel [using ImageMagick itself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9919956/extract-red-channel-from-image) but I want to do the same but using Wand

It seems to me that it is not implemented in Wand, or I miss something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It seems to me that it is not implemented in Wand, or I miss something?

This was implemented in Wand version 0.3.0, but not well documented.

```py
from wand.image import Image

with Image(filename='wizard:') as img:
    with img.channel_image['red'] as red_channel:
        red_channel.save(filename='red_channel.png')
```

[image: red_channel]

Answer (score 0):

Found a workaround using `color_matrix` :

```
img.color_matrix([
    [1, 0, 0],
    [1, 0, 0],
    [1, 0, 0],
])
```